# QInputDialog to appear in the monitor I have focus

Tags: qt

I have a 2-monitor setup and when I spawn a QInputDialog it always spawns in the left monitor, ie the one I generally dont use that much. Is there a way to indicate to appear in the monitor I have focus without incurring in any (x,y) positioning stuff.

Basically I dont care where it appears as long as it the monitor with focus.

Comment: QInputDialog usually appear in the center of its parent window. Unless you create the input dialog, then its parent is deleted?

Answer (score 1):

You can use QDesktopWidget (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html) to find out which screen your MainWindow is being displayed on. This is going to be the screen with "*the focus*", I assume.

You then use the screen number to find out the geometry of the screen and place place the QInputDialog in the screen's center - either before the dialog is shown or right afterwards.

I'm afraid this solution is using "*(x,y) positioning stuff*", but if you find a way to place the dialog without it, let me know.